# Assigning a value to a gridview

Tags: gridview

I am attempting to display data from my database into a gridview
How can I assign the value to the gridview?

```
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            ///Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
            gridview1.Text = rdr[0];
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

gridview.datasource=cmd.ExecuteReader();
gridview.databind();

Answer (score 0):

```
sql_connection = new SqlConnection(conn_str);
sql_command = new SqlCommand(query, sql_connection);
sql_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
sql_adapter.SelectCommand = sql_command;

sql_connection.Open();
sql_adapter.Fill( dataSet1.Tables.GridViewDataTable );
sql_connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable;
SqlDatadapter.Fill(dt);
gridview1.DataSource=dt;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the datasource property of GridView and assign it to the DataTable and
the call the DataBind method on gridview.